# Filling out an empty matrix using functions and loops in R

Tags: r, function, loops

**So my main question are:**

1. is it possible to make a loop add to the next free row in my vector.
2. Is it possible to define the variable in a function the last available variable in a vector/matrix?

**Context:**

I am currently modelling plant growth in r.

I have created multiple empty vectors (each representing different elements of the plants such as its net biomass) that should fill out after every every interval to create a sort of data set where each column represents an hour/interval of growth.

for example:

```
# Creating an empty vector to keep
# track of Nitrogen content in the leaf over 100h.
Nleaf = matrix(nrow=100,ncol=1,0);
```

The nitrogen content at the start of each interval is used as a constant in functions with loops and is reevaluated at the end of the hour interval.

I want the Nleaf matrix to add this new nitrogen content automatically at the end of the hour interval and then use this value in the next time interval.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post with such code and not as hard to read comments. Please delete long comment afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way to do this is as follows. First, start with your empty matrix:

```r
Nleaf <- matrix(nrow = 100, ncol = 1, 0)
```

Now, define the function that you need to apply to the last hour's result to get the next hour's result (*obviously I've had to just make my own function up since you didn't share one in the question. This just multiplies the last hour by 0.9 and adds 0.11*):

```r
calculate_next_hour <- function(last_hour) last_hour * 0.9 + 0.11
```

Now we do a `for` loop to fill the column. We want to start by taking the first hour (`Nleaf[1]`) as the input to our function, and storing it in `Nleaf[2]`, then moving to `Nleaf[2]` and putting the output of that into  `Nleaf[3]`. In general, we want to do `Nleaf[i + 1] <- calculate_next_hour(Nleaf[i])` for each number `i` between 1 and 99. We write that like this:

```
for(i in 1:99) Nleaf[i + 1] <- calculate_next_hour(Nleaf[i])
```

And we're done. Since 100 rows is a lot to show here, I'll just show the first 20, which we can do with the `head` function:

```
head(Nleaf, 20)
#>            [,1]
#>  [1,] 0.0000000
#>  [2,] 0.1100000
#>  [3,] 0.2090000
#>  [4,] 0.2981000
#>  [5,] 0.3782900
#>  [6,] 0.4504610
#>  [7,] 0.5154149
#>  [8,] 0.5738734
#>  [9,] 0.6264861
#> [10,] 0.6738375
#> [11,] 0.7164537
#> [12,] 0.7548083
#> [13,] 0.7893275
#> [14,] 0.8203948
#> [15,] 0.8483553
#> [16,] 0.8735198
#> [17,] 0.8961678
#> [18,] 0.9165510
#> [19,] 0.9348959
#> [20,] 0.9514063
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>